# C# Deserialize without key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using C# to parse a web API that returns a JSON data.

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "items": {
            "Items 1's name": {
                "index": [
                    1
                ],
                "data": {
                    "1": {
                        "special1": {
                            "special2": [
                                {
                                    "value": "4 usd"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

I have managed to parse "response" to "success" part using

```
public class ResponseResult {
        [JsonProperty("response")]
        public bpResponse Response { get; set; }
    }

    public class bpResponse {
        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public string Success { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Item items { get; set; }
    }

using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(data))) {
    var js = new JsonSerializer();
    var u = js.Deserialize<ResponseResult>(jr);
    Console.WriteLine(u.Response.Current_Time);
}
```

And I'm stuck after this as I realized that for the item's name, there is no key available. Can some one guide me on how to continue parsing the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of you problems, that it's not valid JSON, you missing quotes around "4 usd" and closing bracket at the end

Comment: Your Json structure contains property names as values like '1'. The structure doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have valid JSON, then you can deserialize it using next structure:

```
public class ResponseResult
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public bpResponse Response { get; set; }
}

public class bpResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("Items 1's name")]
    public ItemFirstName ItemFirstName { get; set; }
}

public class ItemFirstName
{
    [JsonProperty("index")]
    public List<string> Index { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public First First { get; set; }
}

public class First
{

    [JsonProperty("special1")]
    public Special1 Special1 { get; set; }
}

public class Special1
{
    [JsonProperty("special2")]
    public List<Special2> Special2 { get; set; }
}

public class Special2
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is "special1" and "special2" is dynamic? Means the text can random change throughout the data?

Comment: @user2301818 then in `Data` class replace `First` property type to `JObject`